# Is it possible to listen on two net.createServer()s in a single node.js process?

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a test harness that interacts with another node application and verifies that the other application works properly. I need to be able to listen to two different protocols, on two different ports, in the same process in node.js. Specifically, I am intercepting a simple line-break text protocol (acceptorone) and HTTP requests (acceptortwo).

I currently have this:

```
var acceptorone = net.createServer();
acceptorone.listen(portone);
var acceptortwo = http.createServer();
acceptortwo.listen(porttwo);
```

Yet when I try this I get `Error: listen EADDRINUSE`. Both codepaths work fine independently, everything is fine if one of the listen()s is commented out.

Googling around a bit yields a solution that involves forking off several processes. However, this is running in a test framework so I need to keep everything inside the same process. Applications such as [statsd](https://github.com/etsy/statsd) have no qualms accepting TCP and UDP connections simultaneously, so I'm not sure why there would be a limitation on listening on multiple TCP sockets at the same time. Can anyone shed light on the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something else must be broken with your example; can you show how you initialize `portone` and `porttwo`?

```
$ cat servers.js 
#!/usr/bin/node
net = require('net')
http = require('http')

portone=10000
porttwo=10001

var acceptorone = net.createServer();
acceptorone.listen(portone);
var acceptortwo = http.createServer();
acceptortwo.listen(porttwo);
$ ./servers.js &
[1] 6894
$ netstat -anp | grep node
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6894/node       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6894/node       
$
```

Comment: Aha! Since this was in a test framework, servers were being created and destroyed repeatedly. I was only close()ing one of the acceptors, not both. This lead to the EADDRINUSE I was seeing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Excellent; I think you ought to add that as an answer in your own right, so future visitors will find the information more easily: _beware your testing infrastructure_. :)